# Can "vorhin" be used instead of "von vorhin" in this sentence?

Tags: preposition, time

Reading this sentence in chapter 16 of Peter Stamm's novel "Die sanfte Gleichgültigkeit der Welt":

> "Lena ging mir voraus zum Ausgang, wo der Verkäufer **von vorhin** stand".

Is it just a question of style or could "vorhin" had been used without a preceding "von" in this sentence ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It would make a big difference in terms of meaning:

- > "Lena ging mir voraus zum Ausgang, wo *der Verkäufer* **von vorhin** stand"

  This refers to the seller. "The *salesman* **from before**."

  (Lena went ahead of me to the exit, where the seller from before was standing.)
- > "Lena ging mir voraus zum Ausgang, wo der Verkäufer **vorhin** stand"

  "... where he was standing **before**."

  (Lena went ahead of me to the exit where the seller was standing earlier.)

In both sentences the part "**, wo der Verkäufer (...) stand**" refers to the exit. It is a (local) relative clause like this:

> „Zukunft ist *der Ort*, **wo** wir den Rest unseres Lebens verbringen.“
> (Woody Allen)

The subordinate clause after the comma describes the place more precisely.

---

Theoretically it would be possible to say something like that:

> "Lena ging mir voraus zum Ausgang, wo der Verkäufer **von vorhin vorhin** stand."

(Lena went ahead of me to the exit where the salesman **from earlier** was standing **before**.)

Comment: So "vorhin" on it's own focuses back on the exit rather than the salesman ?

Comment: @JohnLamb I hope i didn't confuse you with this. Both sentences refer to the exit, of course. 
I have adapted my answer once again.

Comment: *Vorhin*, being an adverb, focuses on *stand*, whereas *von vorhin* is an attribute of *der Verkäufer*.

Comment: I would, also change the word order for the "vorhin" sentence to ".., wo vorhin der Verkäufer stand".
It both focuses on the salesman, but as I understand it it's something like the following:
"von vorhin" states the fact that there was a salesman and
"vorhin" states more von the time, when this occured (it feels you really doubt he is still there).
edit: @choXer: yes, but it sounds more natural if the "vorhin" is on the first position.

Comment: @MarkLösche the word order doesn't affect the meaning